# Customise Xcode behaviour for Refactor Extract Method

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode9, xcode10

Is there a way to configure the Xcode refactoring for "Extract Method" so the `extractedFunc` is placed below—*instead of above*—the method from which I'm extracting?

[image: Xcode Method extraction]

Comment: Unfortunately not. But Xcode places method above because in ObjC there was a problem that compiler needs to see a method declaration before you can call it, so all extractions were done this way before, that's why they inherited for swift the same way.

Comment: How many years ago it was? I'm pretty sure there is no such requirement for Objective-C starting from at least Xcode 4.